# Funções R - Caractere Estranho

Tags: r, funções

Criei uma função no R e detectei um caractere estranho aparecendo no retorno da função. Vocês podem me explicar?

Aqui está a função:

```
funcao_categorica <- function(xx){
  rr <- prop.table(table(xx))*100
  return(rr)
}
```

Quando usada, aparece o `xx` acima da tabela retornada.

Vocês sabem me explicar o porquê?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está usando a função `table()` que resulta em um objeto `table` no R que contém um nome para cada dimensão.

Por exemplo, com a seguinte matrix `m`:

```
m <- matrix(1:8, 4)
> matrix(1:8, 4)
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    5
 [2,]    2    6
 [3,]    3    7
 [4,]    4    8
```

A função `table(m)` terá o nome do objeto, no caso "m":

```
> table(m)
m
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Então o caractere estranho é simplemente o nome do objeto utilisado.

Tirar esse caractere vai depender do formato que você quer no retorno da função. Por exemplo, se quiser continuar com o formato `table` você pode usar o argumento `dnn = ''` (que permite também renomear o `table`:

```
> prop.table(table(m, dnn = ''))

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125
```

Ou você pode simplesmente converter o objeto para um `data frame`:

```
> data.frame(prop.table(table(m)))
  m  Freq
1 1 0.125
2 2 0.125
3 3 0.125
4 4 0.125
5 5 0.125
6 6 0.125
7 7 0.125
8 8 0.125
```

Comment: Perfeito. O parâmetro da função acaba sendo o nome da dimensão utilizada. Compreendi. Estas especificações estão listada na documentação? Onde você localizou-as?

Comment: As especificações estão na documentação: `?table`